# vsCode golang run script with 2 files

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

im pretty new to vsCode and golang.
im trying to run using vsCode a script "Main.go" and the script calls for a function in "function.go" that returns an integer

when i run go using command console (go run main.go function.go) there isnt any problem but when i try to run it using vsCode debugger (F5 or ctrl+F5) it wont work.

wanted to know if there's any way to fix it using the launch.json file or settings?

Comment: Do you have delve installed? this is the official docs: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code

Comment: I use liteIDE which is golang specific , F5 works very well. I think you have configure either delve or gdb with vscode